# Make a variable constant or read only in run time in c language?

Tags: c

In a c program how can i make a normal integer or char variable to read only during run time?

Say i have a variable
 `int i=10;` 
After checking a flag i need to convert it to readonly, No one should be able to change it after that.

```
if(TRUE==checkFlag)
{
   //Make i=20 and readonly
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. You can use function*s* to that effect though.

Comment: There is no such thing as "read only" in the C standard.

Comment: You can use `const int i=10;` and it is initialised but read only.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

A variable can have the `const` qualifier applied to it to prevent code from modifying that variable.  This however only applies at compile time.  There is nothing built in to the language to do this a run time.

What you can do is put this variable in an external module and make it accessible only via getter/setter functions.  Then you can set a flag internal to the module that prevents the setter function from making a change.

For example:

ro_var.h:

```
int getx(void);
int setx(int val);
void flag(void);
```

ro_var.c:

```
static int x;
static int ro = 0;

int getx(void)
{
    return x;
}

int setx(int val)
{
    if (ro) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        x = val;
        return 1;
    }
}

void flag(void)
{
    ro = 1;
}
```